# UIIMagePickerController crash on dismissing on iPad ios 6.0

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I work on iPad 4 with iOS 6.0.

I have a ViewController (MyPickerController) with the following init:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        _picker.delegate = self;
        _picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self.view addSubview:_picker.view];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I implement the following UIPickerControllerDelegate method to dimiss MyPickerController:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Well, I have another view controller showed modally in `FormSheetStyle` and  when I tap on a button I want to show `MyPickerController` with the following code:

```
MyPickerController * pickerVC = [[MyPickerController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:pickerVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In my AppDelegate i Have the following totation method:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    
    return (NSUInteger)[application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:window] | (1<<UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    
}
```

When I tap on cancel button of `UIIMagePicker` into `MyPickerController`, the application crashes with the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!
```

Reading related questions on stackoverflow, I create also the follwing UIImagePickerController category:

```
@implementation UIImagePickerController (NonRotating)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

@end
```

Thank you!

Comment: why you add the view of the picker as a subview of your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this..

If your view controller is inside a UINavigationController, you should use this category for the navigationcontroller:

```
@implementation UINavigationController (autorotate)

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}


@end
```